# Novel about boy facing the apocalyptic beliefs of his family

Tags: identification-request

I read this children's novel by getting it from the library, but I gave it back and can't find it again no matter where I search. The plot is about a boy whose father believes that "signs," omens, and events show that the end of the world is coming soon. The family has to build an underground shelter to prepare for this,  but the boy starts having doubts and has to choose between family and the outside. The cover includes a starry,  dark night sky. The title is three words: first one is "chasing," "running," or something similar, the second is "the," and the third is "night, " "dark, " "stars, " or something similar. I have been looking up combinations of such words,  but the results so far weren't of the book I was looking for. It was published fairly recently. In the version I read, there was an advertisement for another book,  which was about children who were told they lived after the world's end, but the tale they were told was doubtful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Watch the Sky](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22875507-watch-the-sky) by Kirsten Hubbard

[image: cover]

> The signs are everywhere, Jory's stepfather, Caleb, says. Red leaves
>   in the springtime. Pages torn from a library book. All the fish in the
>   aquarium facing the same way. A cracked egg with twin yolks.
>   Everywhere and anywhere. And because of them Jory's life is far from
>   ordinary. He must follow a very specific set of rules: don't trust
>   anyone outside the family, have your works at the ready just in case,
>   and always, always watch out for the signs. The end is coming, and
>   they must be prepared.
>
> School is Jory's only escape from Caleb's tight grasp, and with the
>   help of new friends Jory begins to explore a world beyond his family's
>   farm. As Jory's friendships grow, Caleb notifies Jory's mother and
>   siblings that the time has come for final preparations.
>
> They begin an exhausting schedule digging a mysterious tunnel in
>   anticipation of the disaster. But as the hold gets deeper, so does the
>   family's doubt about whether Caleb's prophecy is true. When the stark
>   reality of his stepfather's plans becomes clear, Jory must choose
>   between living his own life or following Caleb, shutting his eyes to
>   the bright world he's just begun to see.

Comment: Thanks so much,  @Ayshe!  I guess I couldn't find it because I somewhat misremembered the title,  so it's amazing you found it so fast.  I feel so relieved!